# Distinct Query in Mongo using Java Mao Access Pattern

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mongo

I want to run a distinct query in mongo db using the spring framework java API. The query is something  like this :

```
db.location.distinct("state");
```

How do I create the Query object for the above. Below is a bad try.

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;

public List<Location> getLocations(int skipCount, int pageSize) 
{
        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("state").is("distinct);
        return mongoOperations.find(query, Location.class);
        /*
         Don't want to do the below, as using Mao Pattern  --
         DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("location");
         DBObject o1 = new BasicDBObject();
         List list = collection.distinct("state", o1);
         return list;
       */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There actually is not a `.distinct()` method directly on MongoOperations, nor anything that really translates to one, save the aggregation framework.

But you can just grab the method from the underlying Collection object directly:

```
List states = mongoOperations.getCollection("location").distinct("state");
```

Where of course to need to supply the collection name, as the Collection object from `.getCollection()` comes from the underlying Java driver.

Or if you prefer, you can run the "command" form directly, but you still need to name the collection:

```
 BasicDBObject distinctCommand = new BasicDBObject("distinct", "location")
            .append("key", "state");
 List states = (List)mongoOperation.executeCommand(distinctCommand).get("values");
```